# Faulty sensor detection?

Tags: statistics, algorithms, coding-theory

Suppose I have N amount of sensors. One of them is faulty. I can detect that there is a faulty sensor by getting the variance of all the sensors. If the variance is large I can assume the data isn't similar which should be the case in a normal sensor.

How do I then detect which sensor is faulty?

Example:
Let's say, S1, S2, and S3 have detected values of 10,10,10 respectively, In this case, the variance is 0.

But let's say S3 failed and gave value 2. In that case, the variance is 21.333...
By setting a threshold for variance. Let's say, 20 we can detect that we have fault in sensors. (The values aren't close to the same)

How do I then detect which one is faulty? Can mean or standard-deviation help in anyways? Or do I need something else?

Comment: This might be too naive but you could take the measurements $S_i$, compute their sample mean $\hat{\mu}$, and see which deviation $|S_i-\hat{\mu}|$ is largest (or you could also check to see if this deviation is greater than $k$ standard deviations).

Comment: You cannot detect which is faulty just from a single variance measurement, as you clearly get the same variance calculation if $S_1$ or $S_2$ is faulty. I think you will have to test all of them one by one essentially.

Comment: The faulty one is the one that gives different values than the others.  Or do you mean you can't access values of individual sensors, just the variances of sets of sensors?

Comment: With $2^n$ sensors, you could figure out which is faulty from $n$ variance measurements.  Number the sensors in base $2$ from $0...0$ to $1...1$, and for each $d$ from $1$ to $n$ check the variance of the set of sensors with numbers having $d$'th bit $1$.